# Can Objectify library be used outside GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I want to use the Google Cloud Datastore. However, I am not using GAE.

Can I still use the Objectify library? If so how? The documentation doesnt say anything about how to configure it to authenticate against Datastore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

Here is a [comment from the creator](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/objectify-appengine/J54xpfi8ua0) on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Objectify is meant for use within GAE only. Other ORM for Java which can interface with the Datastore, such as JDO, JPA, etc. are similar.

In order to access your Datastore from the outside world, you'll either want to write handlers within your GAE app's API which can do the Datastore interfacing for you, simply hitting those methods on your API which are meaningful in the context of your app, or you'll use the [Google Cloud Datastore API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/datastore/v1beta2), allowing your external app to directly touch your Datastore.