# Provide web-safe representation of key that I can use to look up the entity

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore

I want to use the [Datastore Java API to retrieve an entity](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#Datastore_Retrieving_an_entity), but I seem to have a problem preparing the key for the lookup.

This is how the key should look like in the JSON representation

```
partition_id {
  dataset_id: "mydataset"
}
path_element {
  kind: "MyKind"
  id: 1234567890
}
```

However, creating the key form scratch using [DatastoreHelper.makeKey(Object...)](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/javadoc/com/google/api/services/datastore/client/DatastoreHelper#makeKey-java.lang.Object...-), with parameters `MyKind` and the id `1234567890` only populates the `path_element` part, and using such a key in a [lookup request](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/javadoc/com/google/api/services/datastore/DatastoreV1.LookupRequest) does not return any results. For now, I populate the key with dataset id, but it just does not feel right.

I provide the ID via a REST API to the clients and for a simple load, I don't want to require additional information, just the kind and the key.

Is there an API I haven't seen yet that uses a kind/id combination to easily retrieve an entity? I cannot use [Objectify Keys](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities#keys) to just [load the entity](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/BasicOperations#obtaining-an-objectify-instance) using the id, because it seems [Objectify does not work with protobuffers](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/objectify-appengine/J54xpfi8ua0/discussion) (via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30447247)).

Comment: Populating `partition_id.dataset_id` is optional. You should get the same result whether or not it's populated (the server automatically populates it based on the project to which the request is sent).

Comment: @EdDavisson I thought so, but it does not automatically populate in my environment. This might only be an issue with the [local datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/javadoc/com/google/api/services/datastore/client/LocalDevelopmentDatastore), but unfortunately for now, the only way to create a key that works, involves populating the `dataset_id` myself. Thank you very much for your answer, I'll try with a production-like setup.

Comment: It sounds like a bug. Did you populate the dataset_id when you inserted the data? I'm wondering if it didn't match the dataset_id that was set in LocalDevelopmentDatastore? If you have a chance to file a bug with repro instructions, I can try to take a look: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore.

Comment: @EdDavisson Sorry for the late update. I created a very small test case to simulate the problems I had, but I could not reproduce this. Since last week I also updated the code I am using and I cannot reproduce the problem anymore and just removed the workaround. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks for following up, @Kariem! I'll post an answer below summarizing the current state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cloud Datastore API doesn't currently define a canonical web-safe key representation, but we would like to eventually.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/88